# Least square optimalization with huge numbers

Tags: python, numpy, lmfit

I have following function which I need to minimize utilizing least square method (I am using lmfit).

```
y = a * exp(-x/b) + c
```

I have for example following data:

```
profitlist = [-10000, 100.00, 1000.00, 100000.00, 1000000.00]
utilitylist = [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 1]
```

App returns the following error:

```
ValueError: NaN values detected in your input data or the output of your objective/model function - fitting algorithms cannot handle this! Please read https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/faq.html#i-get-errors-from-nan-in-my-fit-what-can-i-do for more information.
```

Problem seems to be that: **exp(-x/b)** returns **inf** or **-inf** if profitList contains any bigger negative number (-1000 worked, -100000 not). So it overflows probably.

The values in the profitList can be **very large float numbers** and they are not always the same. So how can I optimize it with these huge numbers? It seems that lmfit does not support decimal numbers which would fix the issue... What can I do to make it work?

```
class LeastSquares:
def __init__(self, profitList, utilityList):
    self.profitList = np.asarray(profitList)
    self.utilityList = np.asanyarray(utilityList)

def function(self, params, x):
    a = params["a"]
    b = params["b"]
    c = params["c"]

    return a * np.exp(-x/b) + c

def residual(self, params, x, y):
    return (y - self.function(params, x))**2

def setParameters(self, a_start, b_start, c_start):
    parameters = Parameters()
    parameters.add(name="a", value=a_start, min=None, max=0, vary=True)
    parameters.add(name="b", value=b_start, vary=True, min=0.1, max=None)
    parameters.add(name="c", value=c_start, vary=True)
    return parameters 

def startOptimalization(self):
    parameters = self.setParameters(-1, 1, 1)    
    result = minimize(self.residual, parameters, args=(self.profitList, self.utilityList), method="leastsq")
    result.params.pretty_print()

    print(fit_report(result))
    print("SSE")
    print(np.sum(result.residual))
```

Comment: Why not switch units in `profitlist` to make them more comparable to the numbers in `utilitylist` ? Otherwise, I would doubt the numerical stability of any answer.

Comment: @JohnColeman how would I do that? If I divided all numbers in profitList by lets say 1 000 000 than I would not get the same results i think?

Comment: Why would you want to get the same results if you can't trust them? In any event, measuring profit in millions of dollars is common enough. You could also explore moves like multiplying the numbers in `utilitylist` by 100 so that the units are percentages.

Comment: Try using a much larger value for the initial guess of the parameter `b`.

Answer (score 1):

As you see, `numpy.exp(arg)` gives Infinity for any argument greater than ~709, and you will need to avoid such extreme values.  The underlying solvers simply cannot solve them. Since your argument for `arg` is `-x/b`, you need to make sure that `b` is not so small as to blow up the argument to `numpy.exp()`.

In fact, your code shows that you do set a lower bound on `b` of 0.1.
But with values of `profitlist` extending to 1e7, that lower bound is too small to prevent Infinity - your lower limit on `b` would have to be around 14,000.

If your values for `profitlist` are changing for each optimization run,  you may need to do something like this (in your `startOptimization`):

```
   parameters = self.setParameters(-1, 1, 1)    
   parameters['b'].min = max(abs(self.profitList))/700.0
   result = minimize(self.residual, parameters, args=(self.profitList, self.utilityList), method="leastsq")
   result.params.pretty_print()
```

Also, when fitting exponential changes, it is often helpful to compute your exponential model function, and then take the residual as the logarithm of your data and the logarithm of your model, effectively doing the fit in log-space, as you would likely plot the data.

And, finally, don't take the square or the sum of squares of the difference yourself, just return the residual array with sign in tact.  That is, you will probably be better off using something like:

```
def residual(self, params, x, y):
    return np.log(y) - np.log(self.function(params, x))
```

Comment: thanks. First thing - why does maximum of profiList need to be divided by 700? How did you get this number? Secondly - it deals with huge positive numbers but it does not deal with negative ones... if profitList is like: [-10000, 10, 100, 1000, 10000] the issue still persists :/

Comment: and huge positive numbers works even without setting minimum of b with the code you provided (i tried to 1e18). Bigger negative numbers are issues... so if in the profitList is not bigger positive number from you can get minimum for b, it does not work... :/ so as I mentioned the array in my previous comment does not work for example...

Comment: @Nyrnius As for why dividing max of profitList by 700, the idea is to keep the arg of the exponent below +700 (the negative end doesn't matter so much, sending the exponential to 0).  But if you are using `exp(-x/b)` instead of `exp(x/b)` then perhaps you should be taking `max(abs(profitList))/700`.

Comment: thanks again. It helped - but it still fails if i have array like: [-10000, 10, 100, 10000] - it seems that negative number blows up np.exp sooner than positive number. So setting min to b=max(abs(profitlist))/700 - in this case b=10000/700 and it still fails... if I set b to max(abs(profitList))*10/700 then it works, but b is much higher than it is necessary and it seems that i am getting more often high SSE but this might be just coincidence

Comment: The argument of `np.exp()` needs to be <709 to avoid Infinity. It's a feature of floating point math.  If you are using `np.exp(-x/b)` and `x` is -100,000, then `b` must to be larger than 142.  To be clear, `exp(700)` is 1e304.  There is not enough space left in this comment to write out that many zeros!